# Onelogin PHP SAML toolkit and cert fingerprint

Tags: php, saml, onelogin

I would like to know if it is possible to configure the Onelogin SAML PHP toolkit with the fingerprint of the IdP cert only, or must I have the full X.509 certificate?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes is possible. Use the 'certFingerprint' parameter of the 'idp'. There is also the 'certFingerprintAlgorithm' that you should set if not using rsa-sha1. Review the settings [1].

Take in mind 'x509cert' will not be necesary to validate SAMLResponse (enough with certFingerprint and certFingerprintAlgorithm ) but is required to validate signatures of the HTTP-Redirect bindings of the LogoutRequest and LogoutResponse.

[1] https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml#settings